# Why don't we create a chat room?

Tags: discussion

I think that we need a chat room, just like in some other SE websites, where we can ask some off-topic stuff (etc.), show off new questions, discuss about something etc.

For example [Anime&Manga.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/)'s [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) is a good example, they ask for suggestions and opinions there and serious questions in [Anime&Manga.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/).

ps. This question/suggestion feels a bit short for me, but it's late in here (and not in USA, this is why I post it now) and I think that it is self-explanatory. However, feel free to edit and improve.

Comment: Also: not sure if tag should be discussion or feature request.

Comment: ... Somebody who used Chat.SE has never heard of The Bridge. Wow. Our frivolous flag game is clearly slipping. I blame @wipqozn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We already have a bunch of chat rooms! Our most popular and main one is [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) where there is usually a bunch of people around so if you have, say, an ITG you are wondering about or just want to hang out with a bunch of awesome like-minded folk, there's definitely people to talk to most of the time (there's usually a lull around midnightish EST til the Europeans wake up, though).

We also have a bunch of lesser used rooms for various things, like our [Monster Hunter chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7990/monster-hunter), or our [Minecraft chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk), or our [League of Legends chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift), if those are more your style.

Come! Chat! We're really nice, I promise.

Comment: "One chat room to bind them all" is what I say :D (However, feel free to delete now)

Comment: No worries, it's a perfectly alright question :) As a further tip, if you are on any site, and click the Stack Exchange dropdown in the top left of the top bar on a page, you will see a link for the chats for whatever site you are on. :)

Comment: I saw them before but the name "The Bridge" made me think that it is a chatroom for people playing the game "The Bridge". Also "Monster Hunter" made me think the same again.

Comment: Well, in the case of Monster Hunter, you were right. As for the Bridge, the description does say "General Arqade chat room" - a lot of SE sites have fun names for their main rooms :)

Comment: If only The Bridge were a popular enough game to have two million chat messages about it.

Comment: @StrixVaria yeah, I though "Wow, that game must be popular!".

Comment: @AshleyNunn  I saw the chatroom on the right on the page so It doesn't show a description.